# AWS Lambda Environment Variable

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

When I add an environment variable to a aws-lambda through the aws-lambda console, I am able to reference these variables using:

```
import os
# ...
print("environment variable: " + os.environ['variable'])
```

How would I use an environment variable in aws-lambda within a cloudformation template? I don't want to declare the environment variable in the aws-lambda console.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

According [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-function.html), `AWS::Lambda::Function` resource has [`Environment` property](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-lambda-function-environment.html) that you may use for specifying environment variables. So your resource in a cloud formation file would look like:

```
{
  "Type" : "AWS::Lambda::Function",
  "Properties" : {
    "FunctionName" : "Your function name",
    "Environment" : {
        "Variables": {
           "variable1": "value1",
           "variable2": "value2"
        }
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - would I be able to assign these environment variables to a variable in the lambda? So i would do : 
...
variable 1 = os.environ['variable1']) and
variable 2 = os.environ['variable2'])

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [YAML template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-formats.html) for declaring the cloud formation configuration, then you can define your environment variable under Parameters like:

```
Parameters:
  Domain: {Type: String, Default: 'test', AllowedValues: ['test', 'gamma', 'prod']}
  ...
```

And then use it where you have declared the Lambda Resources like below

```
Resources:
  LambdaFunction:
    Properties:
      Environment:
        Variables:
          DOMAIN: {Ref: Domain}
          .......
```